# AESGCM decryption failing with MAC

Tags: c#, json, encryption, cryptography

I have to encrypt some private fields and I found ([jbtule's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637783/jbtule)) class [using AESGCM](https://gist.github.com/jbtule/4336842#file-aesgcm-cs).

When I just encrypt and decrypt it works fine:

```
string nonSecretPayload = "asda23432a3@!$#@#%a";                        
string encryptThisStr = "CakeCat";
string key = "12345678912365478912365478965412";

var encryptAESGCM = AESGCM.SimpleEncrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptThisStr), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonSecretPayload));

//addedJson += "c" + count + "{\"" + @Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptAESGCM) + "\"}";


var decrypyAESGCM2 = AESGCM.SimpleDecrypt(encryptAESGCM , Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt).Length);
```

But when I save the `encryptAESGCM` byte[] as a string in a json file and then decrypt that string after I do a `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` on it it fails with:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: mac check in GCM failed
       at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.GcmBlockCipher.DoFinal(Byte[] output, Int32
    outOff) in C:\BouncyCastle\crypto\src\crypto\modes\GCMBlockCipher.cs:line 295
       at Encryption.AESGCM.SimpleDecrypt(Byte[] encryptedMessage, Byte[] key, I
    nt32 nonSecretPayloadLength)
```

I see that it uses MAC to check that the cyphertext has not been tampered with. All I do is add the encrypted result (byte[]) into a json string as a string using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptAESGCM)` and then saving that to Couchbase. When I get it back I `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptAESGCM)` the stored string and then try and decrypt it. Would this affect the mac? Is there a way around this? Is there another problem?

Comment: When decrypting you are using `salt` which did not play a role when encrypting.

Comment: Sorry I cut out code and missed the part where I saved it to the db. The salt (nonSecretPayload) I used gets saved and the retrieved as the var salt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to arbitrary binary data. It can only decode bytes that were the result of encoding a string with UTF-8. The .net implementation will silently corrupt the data instead of throwing an exception by default.

You should use Base64 instead: [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx)

Comment: THANKS! That seems to have fixed the problem. Also gives me something to go read up about.

Comment: @ShaunGroenewald also that class I wrote has overloads that that take a string for the message and returns a base 64 cipher text.

Comment: @jbtule Thanks, I found them and it helped a lot after I broke my code again.